# What is the purpose of `.Internal()`?

Tags: r

See the following. I don't understand what the purpose of .Internal is. Its documentation is not clear. Could anybody help me understand when `.Internal` is required and why it is needed?

```
R> f=file('f.R', 'r')
R> .Internal(parse(f, n = -1, NULL, '?', 'f.R', encoding='unknown'))
expression(f = function(x) {
    x
})
R> f=file('f.R', 'r')
R> parse(f, n = -1, NULL, '?', 'f.R', encoding='unknown')
expression(f = function(x) {
    x
})
```

To learn this better, I want to extract the C code from R base and compile it separately, then call .Internal on the compiled binary. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

`.Internal()` is one of the interfaces to functions written in C within R.  The other one is displayed as `.Primitive()`.  You can read about the differences in Chapter 2 of the "R Internals" manual.

You shouldn't call `.Internal()` directly.  It's there so that the R developers can write functions like `parse()` that do some things in R and some things in C.  If you want to do that, you should be using `.C()`, `.Call()`, or `.External()`.  (There's also `.Fortran()` with a Fortran interface.) These are described in the "Writing R Extensions" manual.

Comment: That is exactly what is not clear in the doc. I do want to understand how `.Internal()` works instead of being told not to use it because my purpose is to understand existing R code using `.Internal()`. So `.Internal(parse(...))` should not be understood as calling the R function `parse()` then process the output by `.Internal()`? Instead `.Internal(parse(` should be understood as a whole?

Comment: It is a call to the C function that is labelled `"parse"` in `R_FunTab`, as the docs say.  That part of the table looks like this:  `{"parse",       do_parse,       0,      11,     6,      {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},`, so it's really a call to the C function `do_parse`.

Comment: If I want to extract the code from R base and compile it separately then call .Internal on the compiled binary. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: No, `.Internal` will only call internal entry points that are listed in that table.